# Linear combinaion of powers of a polynomial without lowest terms

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Let $\mathbb K$ be a field and $P$ be a polynomial of $\mathbb K[X]$ such that $\deg(P)\ge1$. Consider a positive integer $s$. Does there exist a non zero polynomial in $\mathrm{Vect}_{\mathbb K}(P^i\mid i\in\mathbb N_0)\cap X^s\mathbb K[X]$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $P(x)$ lacks a constant term you are done, yes?  Similarly if $P^2(x)$ lacks a constant term.  If both have non-zero constant terms then some linear combination of them is non-zero and has no constant term.

Comment: Yes.  $(P(x)-P(0))^s$.

Comment: Thank you both. It missed me !!!